# Order of appearance in nomenclature

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

In fact I want to have a two columns nomenclature in order, but when I write them in order in the result they are not in the order, I have already read the nomencl package : sort by order of appearance, and I have applied the same structure but the problem remains the same. even when I use \nomencalure[order]{symbol}{meaning}. Here is the code:

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,3p,numbers,sort,compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{framed}  
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec1}
 BLABLABLABLABLABALABABLABLABLABLAB\par 
 LABALABABLABLABLABLABLABALABABLABLAB\par
 LABLABLABALABABLABLABLABLABLABALABA

\begin{framed}
\nomenclature[01]{$x_{1}$}{parameter1}
\nomenclature[02]{$x_{2}$}{parameter2}
\nomenclature[03]{$x_{3}$}{parameter3}
\nomenclature[04]{$x_{4}$}{parameter4}
\nomenclature[05]{$x_{5}$}{parameter5}
\nomenclature[06]{$x_{6}$}{parameter6}
\nomenclature[07]{$x_{7}$}{parameter7}
\nomenclature[08]{$x_{8}$}{parameter8}
\nomenclature[09]{$x_{9}$}{parameter9}
\nomenclature[10]{$x_{10}$}{parameter10}
\nomenclature[11]{$\delta$}{parameter11}
\nomenclature[12]{$\theta$}{parameter12}
\nomenclature[13]{$\omega$}{parameter13}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\printnomenclature[1.9cm]
\end{multicols}
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have already read that but I still have the same problem so it's not a duplication, in my case I have a two columns nomenclature

Comment: Well, the columns has nothing to do with `nomenclature`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nomenclature` takes the order of appearance of the entries as an optional argument: `\nomenclature[order number]{symbol}{description}`.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,3p,numbers,sort,compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{framed}  
\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{framed}
\nomenclature[01]{$x_{1}$}{parameter1}
\nomenclature[02]{$x_{2}$}{parameter2}
\nomenclature[03]{$x_{3}$}{parameter3}
\nomenclature[04]{$x_{4}$}{parameter4}
\nomenclature[05]{$x_{5}$}{parameter5}
\nomenclature[06]{$x_{6}$}{parameter6}
\nomenclature[07]{$x_{7}$}{parameter7}
\nomenclature[08]{$x_{8}$}{parameter8}
\nomenclature[09]{$x_{9}$}{parameter9}
\nomenclature[10]{$x_{10}$}{parameter10}
\nomenclature[11]{$\delta$}{parameter11}
\nomenclature[12]{$\theta$}{parameter12}
\nomenclature[13]{$\omega$}{parameter13}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\printnomenclature[1.9cm]
\end{multicols}

\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

which creates the following:

[image]

Comment: it's weird I still have the same problem

Comment: Did you try the same MWE?

Comment: Yes it's weird I copied it and pasted it as you wrote it  but I don't get the result you got